# Требуется подсказка в решении задачи язык Си 1 курс

Tags: c

Дали задачу:

> Ввести одномерный массив  , вывести его. Найти произведение его
>   элементов, принадлежащих интервалу [min / 2, max / 2] . Значением
>   этого произведения заменить первый и предпоследний элементы массива.

Написал ввод массива и вывод. Не понимаю, каким образом "найти произведение его элементов, принадлежащих интервалу [min / 2, max / 2]"

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mass [N];
    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++) 
        scanf (&mass[i]);     
    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)          
        printf ("%d", mass[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что тут не решают учебные задачи за других.

Comment: А какие конкретно сложности у Вас возникли? Покажите Ваши наработки.

Comment: Мне не нужно решение  целиком , я хочу понять , каким образом  "найти произведение его элементов, принадлежащих интервалу [min / 2, max / 2]"

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mass [N];



    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)

        scanf (&mass[i]);
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)
        
        printf ("%d", mass[i]);
        
    


  
    return 0;
}

Comment: Циклы и обращение к элементам массива изучите...

Comment: какое пособие посоветуете?

Comment: @СтепанКотов Преподавателя спросить?...

Comment: @СтепанКотов находите минимальный и максимальный элементы в массиве, делите пополам эти значения. Бежите снова по массиву, перемножая эти элементы, которые входят в эти границы. Заменяете элементы массива. Profit.

Comment: Преподаватель в отпуске, занятия еще не начались

Comment: @СтепанКотов если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эх, с 1 курса на Си не писал. Автор сделал маленькие попытки в создании программы, она простая, предлагаю помочь.

Постарался подправить вопрос, чтобы имел хоть какую-то пользу. Если посчитаете, что это всё-таки решение за автора и вопрос бесполезен в будущем, то удалю ответ.

[ideone](http://ideone.com/kxanju)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int mass[] = {2, 2, -3, 1, 5}; // сразу заполним массив
    int N = sizeof (mass) / sizeof (int); // узнаем его длину
    double min = mass[0], max = mass[0], pr = 1;
    //for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++) 
    //    scanf (&mass[i]);     
    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++) {       
        printf ("%d, ", mass[i]);
        if (min > mass[i]) // ищем минимальный элемент
            min = mass[i];
        if (max < mass[i]) // ищем максимальный элемент
            max = mass[i];
    }
    printf ("\n");
    min = min / 2; // делаем эти границы min/2 и max/2
    max = max / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (mass[i] >= min && mass[i] <= max) {
            pr = pr * mass[i]; // находим произведение тех элементов, которые в данном отрезке
        }
    }

    mass[0] = pr; // заменяем
    mass[N-2] = pr;

    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++) {       
        printf ("%d, ", mass[i]); // profit
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что значит sizeof (int)?

Comment: `sizeof(int)` - возвращает размер типа `int` в байтах по-моему. sizeof(mass) возвращает размер массива в байтах. Поэтому чтобы узнать сколько элементов, делим одно на другое.

Comment: Для получения N лучше сразу писать `sizeof(mass) / sizeof(mass[0])`, если (конечно, не в этой программе) тип при переработке программы изменится, то не придется менять код, вычисляющий размер массива. И еще, при поиске `min`и `max` можно смело написать `else` между этими `if`-ами